# How do I check if a Delphi Prism project is a website?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, delphi-prism

I want to check if a project is a website.

I did it with the `Project` class, with the `Property` property, by checking if `CurrentWebsiteLanguage` has value, or is `null`. However, that doesn't work for Delphi Prism websites.

So, I tried by checking the `AspnetVersion` property, but it throws an exception.

> 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'. Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "check if project is website".

Comment: The project is website if by running it, it opens in a web browser.

Comment: You want to check. Where, when? How does it "not work", which exception?

Comment: @GertArnold ...threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'. Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A google search for that error is bringing up cases where people didn't reference all the assemblies they needed to reference while using the `dynamic` keyword.

- http://www.thinkfarahead.com/2010/05/silverlight-40-dynamic-types-extension.html
- http://forums.silverlight.net/t/169033.aspx/1

Add references in your project to `Microsoft.CSharp.dll` and `System.Core.dll` and that particular error should go away.